# libgdx animation just one time on an event

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx

I'm programming a small game for Android in Libgdx.
I want an Animation just one time in a collision, but the Problem is that the Animation accomplish only in the first collision. After that Nothing happens in the next collision.

```
elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
if (Intersector.overlaps(Circle, cup[i])) {
    batch.draw((TextureRegion) fleckanimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, false));
}
```

If I set the Looping to true, the Animation loops by a collision. but it should execute only one time.

Comment: You need to use time since the animation started instead of elapsed time for the whole game. Youll need another float for that.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to restart elapsedTime when animation is finished, to start animation again when is next collision.